# Setting a height range between the window top and an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an `url` like this `website.com/#site` so that when I load the page the `div name="site"` is highlighted but my problem is that the `div` stays at the very top of the window which causes some obstruction so is there a way with I can push down the `div` element by setting a margin between it and the window top for example

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //set margin between window.height() and div element;
})
```

I would also appreciate other methods apart from `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your aim like this

```
// the margin can be set to any desired value
margin = 200;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$('div').offset().top - margin
}, 2000);
```